# Is there a way to get the state of the environment at the end of execution of a subprocess in PHP?

Tags: php

When my PHP script runs a subprocess (with any of the relevant functions such as `exec()`, `system()`, `passthru()`, `popen()`, `proc_open()`, and maybe others I've forgotten) I can control the values of environment variables the process starts with (either by changing the script's environment itself, or, at least in the case of `proc_open()`, by passing the desired environment as an argument). But is there a way for my script to get the state of the environment the process finishes with (that is the process potentially changes the environment, and I wish my script to be able to track those changes). Using `getenv()` is useless as the script`s environment is not changed by the subprocess. Any ideas regarding whether this can be done, and how?

Comment: what does the process change that you want to determine?

Comment: @Dagon: Anything at all. One important example is `$PWD`. But in general, I want to be able to invoke another process later (later, not immediately, otherwise there would be a simple solution) as if they were run one after the other from the same shell environment.

Comment: Would you be able to save your environment vars to a more persistent location, such as a file? Then in your subprocess, you would 1) load vars, 2) run task, 3) save vars. Might have to write a wrapper script that does precisely those three things, then PHP's `exec()` (or whichever) runs that wrapper. Might be nice if `proc_open()`'s `$env` parameter would also return by reference. Perhaps that's worthy of a feature request?

Comment: Out of interest, I've submitted this as [Request #62913](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62913).

Comment: @Wiseguy: I've been thinking of something along the lines of what you suggested. I hope to get to a working solution and then share it here. And well done on the feature request! While at it, you can request the current working directory, too!

Comment: @Dagon: What aren't you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't like it, but this is what I've come up with: I've written a script that outputs the whole environment as a single line, and I'm calling it right after my invoked process, as part of the same command. After that I can analyse the output, extracting the environment from the last line, and discarding it in order to process the output from my original process.

There are many options to implement this. What I've done is along the lines of:

1) Creating a Python script, naming it, for example `printenv`, which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import os
print os.environ
```

2) When invoking my process, instead of `<some command>` I invoke `<some command> && printenv`.

Of course, the script does not have to be in Python, and it does not have to output the environment in Python's `print` format. (But this format is rather convenient, and can be passed to a JavaScript assignment, for example.)